# Unable to select new solution configuration for setup project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-project, solution

I have a C# project in Visual Studio 2010 with multiple solution configurations (not only Debug an Release). Couple days ago i created another setup project for my project and created a new solution configuration. In configuration manager i can select my new configuration for all projects inside my solution, except my new setup project. In drop down it has only Debug and Release, while other setup project have my new configuration.
Anybody knows where the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution. I manually added necessary configuration to vdproj file after opening it as xml file.

Comment: You can also add it using the Configuration Manager but you will have to make sure that the name is exactly the same with the one usd by the other projects of the solution.